# Expect and --More--

Tags: linux, expect

Im trying to use expect to auto accept an EULA that is prompted in --more--.

```
#!/usr/bin/expect
spawn "./greenplum-perfmon-web-4.1.2.0-build-2-RHEL5-x86_64.bin"
expect "--More--"
send "q"
expect "*****"
send "yes"
expect "*****"
send ""
expect "*****"
send "yes"
```

This does not work and Im not sure why. The script always halts at the --More-- prompt and the second I click ANYTHING it instantly processess the rest of the script.

I have tried with

```
expect -exact "--More--"
```

and

```
expect "the Customer"
(what is written above the --More--)
```

Comment: set `exp_internal 1` to get a better debug output

Comment: change `send "yes"` to `send "yes\r"` if the program expects the user to hit enter. `expect "****"` will probably match anything, since the default matching mode is `-glob` and `*` is a glob-special character: use `expect -exact ****`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try setting `$MORE` to something like `-99999999` so that the `more` prompt never shows up.

Comment: The environment variable. You know, the one that `more` reads to get its options? You know this because you read the man page, right?

Answer (score 0):

A solution avoiding expect altogether:

You could avoid the problem altogether by setting the `PAGER` environment variable to a different program and using the `yes` program. The following turns off yes and sends as many `yes\n` strings into the installer as it will take:

```
PAGER=cat  yes yes | ./greenplum-perfmon-web-4.1.2.0-build-2-RHEL5-x86_64.bin
```

If that looks weird to you, it is almost equivalent to the following:

```
export PAGER=cat
yes yes | ./greenplum-perfmon-web-4.1.2.0-build-2-RHEL5-x86_64.bin
```

The difference is that with the one-liner, `PAGER` is only set for that one command, not for anything that comes afterwards.